# How to do binding (DataSet to Chart) programmatically?

Tags: wpf, binding, graph, dataset

Could anyone identify the problem in this code? (I'm kinda newbie in WPF bindings.)
This code executes after chart is loaded when I click a button:
I get this error:

> **Update:** I dont get that error anymore. Thanks to Tomas.

Now no error occur but chart looks completely blank (no columns)

> **Update:** Code now looks like this:

```
            // create a very simple DataSet
        var dataSet = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
        var table = dataSet.Tables.Add("MyTable");
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Price");
        table.Rows.Add("Brick", 1.5d);
        table.Rows.Add("Soap", 4.99d);
        table.Rows.Add("Comic Book", 0.99d);

        // chart series
        var series = new ColumnSeries()
        {
            IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("[Name]"), // How to deal with
            DependentValueBinding = new Binding("[Price]"), //  these two?
            ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView // or maybe I do mistake here?
        };

        // ---------- set additional binding as adviced ------------------
        series.SetBinding(ColumnSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());

        // chart stuff
        MyChart.Series.Add(series);
        MyChart.Title = "Names 'n Prices";

        // some code to remove legend
        var style = new Style(typeof(Control));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LegendItem.TemplateProperty, null));
        MyChart.LegendStyle = style;
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingzTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="606" Width="988" xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <charting:Chart Name="MyChart" Margin="0,0,573,0" Height="289" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="272,361,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="chart1_Loaded" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: As much as I love the concept of 'Bingings' I have edited the title. :)

Comment: Nice one :D (Hmmm... How could I miss such a mistake?! (scared face))

Comment: It fixed my problem only partially. I don't get chart columns. However I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you must call SetBinding method as noted here http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/151817/350809.aspx

Comment: [Quote name=user175908] It fixed my problem only partially. I don't get chart columns. However I will mark your answer. [End]

Comment: Eh... I found better way using value converters.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda solved it...

```
        // create a very simple DataSet
        var dataSet = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
        var table = dataSet.Tables.Add("MyTable");
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Price");
        table.Rows.Add("Brick", 1.5d);
        table.Rows.Add("Soap", 4.99d);
        table.Rows.Add("Comic Book", 0.99d);
        table.Rows.Add("Broken Table", 10.99d);

        // chart series
        var series = new ColumnSeries()
        {             
            IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"),
            DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value"), 
            ItemsSource = from x in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          select new KeyValuePair<string, double>((string)x["Name"], double.Parse((string)x["Price"]))
        };

        // chart stuff       
        MyChart.Series.Add(series); 
        MyChart.Title = "Names 'n Prices"; 

        // some code to remove legend    
        var style = new Style(typeof(Control)); 
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LegendItem.TemplateProperty, null));   
        MyChart.LegendStyle = style;
```

That SetBinding() stuff only made chart look blank...

LINQ does own, but it adds unneeded complexity. There must be way of doing that without linq... Although I'm satisfied with results.
For now.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Found even better way using value converters:
P.S: I was getting exceptions because objects stored in table was converted to **strings** by defaut. Chart needed **number**... So I wrote a ValueConverter and got everything working.

```
    // create a very simple DataSet
    var dataSet = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
    var table = dataSet.Tables.Add("MyTable");
    table.Columns.Add("Name");         
    table.Columns.Add("Price");
    table.Rows.Add("Brick", 1.5d);
    table.Rows.Add("Soap", 4.99d);   
    table.Rows.Add("Comic Book", 0.99d);   
    table.Rows.Add("Broken Table", 10.99d);  
    // chart series         
    var series = new ColumnSeries()     
    {                          
        IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"), 
        DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value")
        {
             Converter = new Conv()
        },
        ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["MyTable"]; 

    };          
    // chart stuff
    MyChart.Series.Add(series);
    MyChart.Title = "Names 'n Prices";
    // some code to remove legend     
    var style = new Style(typeof(Control)); 
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LegendItem.TemplateProperty, null));                
    MyChart.LegendStyle = style;
```

...

```
 public class Conv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```